# How to add array to array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, forms, multidimensional-array, foreach

So I thought this would be easy, but try as I might various methods of appending values to an array in PHP, I always get NULL.

```
$sites = array();
$sites[0] = $_POST['site0'];
foreach($sites as $site) {
    var_dump($site);
}
```

`$_POST['site0']` is an HTML form array, containing 11 keys and values. I get a `invalid argument` error for line 3. Any reason why this would occur?

Comment: I don't get `null`, but are you sire `_POST[site0]` is set?

Comment: The way to add values to an array is like `$arr[] = 'new item'`; specify more dimensions depending on structure as needed e.g. `$arr[0][] = ...`. It makes no sense at all that `var_dump` would print `null` with the above code. Is that what you really have?

Comment: are you sure there is not typo? Or missing a BIG chunk of code before the var_dump?

Comment: what gives you `var_dump($_POST['site0'])` this code?

Comment: Okay, it seems that the real problem is not that the array $sites is NULL — I have fixed that, it was an error in the HTML — but rather that `foreach($sites as $site)` gives me "invalid argument". There are going to be more sites, and I'd like to cycle through and process them.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, `$_POST['site0']` is null or empty.

You could push the value to the $sites array doing so:

```
$sites[] = $_POST['site0'];
```

The value will be pushed to the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

It's really work. Just check your

```
$_POST['site0'];
```

and try add

```
$sites[1] = 'spam';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me (see [codepad](http://codepad.org/i7ivj9nP)):

**Code**

```
$_POST['site0'] = 'foobar';
$sites = array();
$sites[0] = $_POST['site0'];
var_dump($sites); // returns NULL
```

**Result**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "foobar"
}
```

Try to `var_dump($_POST);` to see what's actually contained in `$_POST`.

Comment: Turns out the problem is slightly different than what I thought it was — I've changed the question to reflect this.